# Return the Response got from fetch/Axios API with POST method - Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, post, axios

I want to know how to return the data of POST method API using fetch

- my API consist of a form data with 2 parameters
- I tried with Axios, I am not getting the data to display or to return the response
- When I have tried with the Fetch, I am able the get the response but not able to return the data to another JS file.

With Fetch :

```
  method: 'POST',
  body: formdata,
  redirect: 'follow'
};
let resp = await fetch('URL',requestOptions)
  .then(res => Promise.all([res.status, res.json()]))
  .then(([status, jsonData]) => {
    console.log('jsonData : ', jsonData);  // here i am getting the response
    console.log('status : ', status);
    console.log('resp : ', resp);  //here i am getting as UNDEFINED

    return resp;
  });
```

With Axios:

```
 let options = {
            'headers': {
            },
            formData: {
              'para1': '';
              'para2': '';
            }
        };

        let resp = await axios.post(URL ,options)
        console.log('---------'+resp+'----------') //i am not getting any response here
        return resp;
```

Even with the **request** i am able to get the response from the api but not able to return the same to another JS file.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you are returning `resp` variable inside the final then, but this is not correct. you should  immediately return it two lines below where it is right now, ie outside of the final then. you return and use a promise immediately, not when its finally resolved!

Comment: Hi @GeorgiB.Nikolov, I didn't get it.. could be please post it as Answer of ur explanation or explain here in brief.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
resp = await fetch('URL',requestOptions)
      .then(res) => {
        console.log(res)
      })
      .catch(e=>{
        console.log(e)
      });
```

with axios

```
    try{
let resp = await axios.post(URL ,options)
        console.log('---------'+resp+'----------') //i am not getting any response here
        return resp;
}
catch(e){
console.log(e)
}
```

Comment: Hi, Abhishek the above-posted variation is not useful, The Axios code returning the response with zero list values in an object. where as fetch it is throwing me an error. can u please have a look and edit it.

Comment: its an issue with your backend code, check the error for more info

Comment: Thank you for the response, it's just I have to stringify my form data using querystring